# Open Hardware Monitor doesn't show all sensors

Tags: temperature, clock, sensors

[image]

I downloaded Open Hardware Monitor and installed mono (to run Open Hardware Monitor) and I installed lm-sensors too. If I run Open Hardware Monitor it shows only fans and voltage, but It doesn't show current CPU clock (and core temperatures), RAM, iGPU / GPU clock / temperature, Discs temperature and SMART info.

In Windows I have no problem. Please can you help me?

**Please don't tell me to use** other softwares for monitoring that things, because I don't want to have X opened applications, Open Hardware Monitor shows everything what I need (clocks, voltage, SMART, temperatures, fan speed) and It is in 1 application.

Thank you for your understanding :)

Comment: You are running a Windows application on Ubuntu and are wondering why you are having problems?

Comment: But it is supported for linux http://openhardwaremonitor.org/screenshots/

Comment: Hrrrmmm... well that's a new one. Have you tried `psensor`?

Comment: Please read section "Please don't tell me to use" :)

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu problem. You should report a  bug to the Mono and/or OHM devs.

Comment: But It can be Ubuntu problem that I am missing some drivers or something

Comment: If `psensor` shows the temps, then you know it's not Ubuntu's problem.

Comment: And what about clocks or SMART?

Comment: You can view the clock with `lscpu | grep MHz`, and the SMART data from the included Disks application.

Comment: My point is, this is **not** Ubuntu's problem.